# Overriding primitive datatypes in java

Tags: java, types

```
public static char int() {
    return "A";
}
```

The above code obviously wont work as **int is a primitive data type** ,
but if a person wants to do that is there any way 
looking for a way to override reserved keyword or create new reserved keyword

Comment: `int()` can't be a valid method name ("int" is a keyword). And... `return "A";` or `return 'A';`?

Comment: "ABC" is no `char` and no, you can't use reserved keywords as identifiers in java

Comment: Also naming your method `int` and returning a `char` is bad design, use **names** that indicate what the method does. e.g. `getA()` even though this would still not make much sense as you could just write `char c = 'A'` at the call site

Answer (score 3):

The way this is generally written e.g. [Number.intValue()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Number.html#intValue()), is the following

```
public static int intValue() {
    return 'A';
}
```

or as a getter

```
private static char a = 'A';

public static char getA() {
    return a;
}
```

You can't use a keyword such as `int` as a method, class or variable name.

Comment: i dont want to typecast or to get int value of a character but to override a reserved keyword or to create one,but i guess thats not possile

Comment: @rahul a `keyword` by definition is reserved. You can't use it for another purpose.

Answer (score 2):

No. `int` is a reserved keyword and there is no way to override that to use it as a method's name.